# How to find the number of iterations of 2 for-loops within another for-loop?

Tags: for-loop, nested, iteration

> sum = 0
>   for i in range (0, n):
>      for j in range(0,i):
>          sum += 1
>      for k in range(0, 20000):
>          sum+= 1

How do I figure out the number of iterations this will have? I know it will be related to n and 20,000 at least. Thanks in advance! Some math on how to get there would be nice too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just multiply the number of times through the outer loop with the sum of the inner loops

total = outer * (inner1 + inner2)

```
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        count++;
    }

    for (var k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thelgevold/qL7ed3m5/6/
    alert(count);

This will be 10 * (10 + 10) = 200

Comment: The last two for loops in my original post are actually within the first for loop. I can't seem to format it correctly.